# NLP - Python - Conditional Frequency Distribution failing

Tags: python, nlp, corpus

Code
It's a hackerrank problem, two test cases provided are getting failed, please if someone can help

```
from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def calculateCFD(cfdconditions, cfdevents):
    # Write your code here
    from nltk.corpus import brown
    from nltk import ConditionalFreqDist
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    stopword = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    cdev_cfd = [ (genre, word.lower()) for genre in cfdconditions for word in brown.words(categories=genre) if word.lower() not in stopword]
    #cdev_cfd = [list(x) for x in cdev_cfd]
    cdev_cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(cdev_cfd)
    a = cdev_cfd.tabulate(condition = cfdconditions, samples = cfdevents)
    inged_cfd = [ (genre, word.lower()) for genre in cfdconditions for word in brown.words(categories=genre) if (word.lower().endswith('ing') or word.lower().endswith('ed')) ]
    inged_cfd = [list(x) for x in inged_cfd]
    for wd in inged_cfd:
        if wd[1].endswith('ing') and wd[1] not in stopword:
            wd[1] = 'ing'
        elif wd[1].endswith('ed') and wd[1] not in stopword:
            wd[1] = 'ed'

    inged_cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(inged_cfd)    
    b = inged_cfd.tabulate(cfdconditions, samples = ['ed','ing'])
    return(a,b)
```

The output for fail test cases are

```
                     many years 
    adventure    24    32 
        fiction    29    44 
science_fiction    11    16 
                  ed  ing 
        fiction 2943 1767 
      adventure 3281 1844 
science_fiction  574  293
```

And

```
                 good    bad better 
      adventure     39      9     30 
        fiction     60     17     27 
        mystery     45     13     29 
science_fiction     14      1      4 
                  ed  ing 
      adventure 3281 1844 
        fiction 2943 1767 
science_fiction  574  293 
        mystery 2382 1374
```

Kindly help me in getting these test cases passed as I am not getting where it is wrong

Comment: Hi Abhi, please note, this is not how you ask a question on SO. Your question is not clear at all as well, nor do you have the error displayed. Please read [ask] and [mre] as this question may be flagged for low quality.

Comment: Thanks @AkshaySehgal, this is the first time I am asking question, will keep these points in mind

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below two lines

```
cdev_cfd = [ (genre, word.lower()) for genre in cfdconditions for word in brown.words(categories=genre) if word.lower() not in stopword]
cdev_cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(cdev_cfd)
```

and replace with

```
cdev_cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist([ (genre, word.lower()) for genre in brown.categories() for word in brown.words(categories=genre) if word.lower() not in stopword and genre in cfdconditions])
```

Answer (score 0):

your code looks good. in order to make this work, just update the word condition to conditions

```
a = cdev_cfd.tabulate(condition = cfdconditions, samples = cfdevents)
with  
a = cdev_cfd.tabulate(conditions = cfdconditions, samples = cfdevents)
```

it will work in flying colors :)